# Using Athena to get terminatingrule from rulegrouplist in AWS WAF logs

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, amazon-waf

I followed [these instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/waf-logs.html) to get my AWS WAF data into an Athena table.

I would like to query the data to find the latest requests with an action of BLOCK. This query works:

```
SELECT
  from_unixtime(timestamp / 1000e0) AS date,
  action,
  httprequest.clientip AS ip,
  httprequest.uri AS request,
  httprequest.country as country,
  terminatingruleid,
  rulegrouplist
FROM waf_logs
WHERE action='BLOCK'
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

My issue is cleanly identifying the "terminatingrule" - the reason the request was blocked. As an example, a result has

```
terminatingrule = AWS-AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet
```

And

```
rulegrouplist = [
  {
    "nonterminatingmatchingrules": [],
    "rulegroupid": "AWS#AWSManagedRulesAmazonIpReputationList",
    "terminatingrule": "null",
    "excludedrules": "null"
  },
  {
    "nonterminatingmatchingrules": [],
    "rulegroupid": "AWS#AWSManagedRulesKnownBadInputsRuleSet",
    "terminatingrule": "null",
    "excludedrules": "null"
  },
  {
    "nonterminatingmatchingrules": [],
    "rulegroupid": "AWS#AWSManagedRulesLinuxRuleSet",
    "terminatingrule": "null",
    "excludedrules": "null"
  },
  {
    "nonterminatingmatchingrules": [],
    "rulegroupid": "AWS#AWSManagedRulesCommonRuleSet",
    "terminatingrule": {
      "rulematchdetails": "null",
      "action": "BLOCK",
      "ruleid": "NoUserAgent_HEADER"
    },
    "excludedrules":"null"
  }
]
```

The piece of data I would like separated into a column is `rulegrouplist[terminatingrule].ruleid` which has a value of `NoUserAgent_HEADER`

AWS provide [useful information on querying nested Athena arrays](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/rows-and-structs.html), but I have been unable to get the result I want.

I have framed this as an AWS question but since Athena uses SQL queries, it's likely that anyone with good SQL skills could work this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me exactly what you want, but I'm going to assume you are after the array element where `terminatingrule` is not `"null"` (I will also assume that if there are multiple you want the first).

The documentation you link to say that the type of the `rulegrouplist` column is `array<string>`. The reason why it is `string` and not a complex type is because there seems to be multiple different schemas for this column, one example being that the `terminatingrule` property is either the *string* `"null"`, or a struct/object – something that can't be described using Athena's type system.

This is not a problem, however. When dealing with JSON there's a whole set of [JSON functions](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/json.html) that can be used. Here's one way to use [`json_extract`](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/json.html#json_extract) combined with [`filter`](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/array.html#filter) and [`element_at`](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/array.html#element_at) to remove array elements where the `terminatingrule` property is the string "null" and then pick the first of the remaining elements:

```sql
SELECT
  element_at(
    filter(
      rulegrouplist,
      rulegroup -> json_extract(rulegroup, '$.terminatingrule') <> CAST('null' AS JSON)
    ),
    1
  ) AS first_non_null_terminatingrule
FROM waf_logs
WHERE action = 'BLOCK'
ORDER BY date DESC
```

You say you want the "latest", which to me is ambiguous and could mean both first non-null and last non-null element. The query above will return the first non-null element, and if you want the last you can change the second argument to `element_at` to -1 (Athena's array indexing starts from 1, and -1 is counting from the end).

To return the individual ruleid element of the json:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(timestamp / 1000e0) AS date, action, httprequest.clientip AS ip, httprequest.uri AS request, httprequest.country as country, terminatingruleid, json_extract(element_at(filter(rulegrouplist,rulegroup -> json_extract(rulegroup, '$.terminatingrule') <> CAST('null' AS JSON)  ),1), '$.terminatingrule.ruleid') AS ruleid
FROM waf_logs
WHERE action='BLOCK'
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer, that's very kind of you. The answer returned the required whole array (json) element. I wanted an individual json element within that array. I hope you don't mind, I went ahead and edited your answer so that any future readers will see my final query. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but the solution posted by Theo didn't work for me, even though the table was created according to the instructions linked to in the original post.

Here is what worked for me, which is basically the same as Theo's solution, but without the json conversion:

```
SELECT
  from_unixtime(timestamp / 1000e0) AS date,
  action,
  httprequest.clientip AS ip,
  httprequest.uri AS request,
  httprequest.country as country,
  terminatingruleid,
  rulegrouplist,
  element_at(filter(ruleGroupList, ruleGroup -> ruleGroup.terminatingRule IS NOT NULL),1).terminatingRule.ruleId AS ruleId
FROM waf_logs
WHERE action='BLOCK'
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: thanks so much for posting this!, works for me.

Comment: Missing a comma after rulegrouplist I believe.

Comment: @totalhack Thanks! I've updated the answer adding the comma.