# AWS Athena WAF Logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-waf

Since AWS updated the WAF logs format, my queries don't work anymore as described here:

[Using Athena to get terminatingrule from rulegrouplist in AWS WAF logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63055676/using-athena-to-get-terminatingrule-from-rulegrouplist-in-aws-waf-logs/68116980#68116980)

I get this error:

```
SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:224: Unexpected parameters (row("rulegroupid" varchar,"terminatingrule" varchar,"nonterminatingmatchingrules" array(row("action" varchar,"ruleid" varchar))), varchar(17)) for function json_extract. Expected: json_extract(varchar(x), JsonPath) , json_extract(json, JsonPath)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this syntax error?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column is no longer a string, and the JSON functions expect a string. It looks like you've changed your schema to use a struct for a column. Struct properties can be accessed directly, e.g. `rulegrouplist[1].rulegroupid`.